# Persisted column throwing non-deterministic error using convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016 and I'm running into a little bit of a problem.

Here's my use case that is causing issues for me...

```
create table dbo.Example (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) not null,
    Email nvarchar(255) not null,
    DOB datetime2(7) not null,
    RowHash as convert(nvarchar(66), hashbytes('SHA1', coalesce(
        convert(nvarchar(max), [Name]), 
        convert(nvarchar(max), Email), 
        convert(nvarchar(max), DOB)
    ))) persisted
    constraint [PK_Example] primary key clustered (Id asc)
);
drop table dbo.Example;
```

The message I'm getting is:

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Computed column 'RowHash' in table 'Example' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

When I set the column to not be persisted, the data type is interpreted correctly as nvarchar(66) however I would like to have it persisted.  The issue seems to be related to the datetime2 column however I have a mixture of data types on the table.

So the goals are to use a persisted hashbytes column to hold a hash of all the values in my table.

Any ideas?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `coalesce()` and not `concat()`?

**Example**

```
create table dbo.Example (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) not null,
    Email nvarchar(255) not null,
    DOB datetime2(7) not null,
    RowHash as convert(nvarchar(66), hashbytes('SHA1', concat(
        [Name], 
        Email, 
        DOB
    ))) persisted
    constraint [PK_Example] primary key clustered (Id asc)
);

Select * from [dbo].[Example]
--drop table dbo.Example;
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: That's a fair point.  I was using coalesce since there are going to be nulls but I see that concat will also handle that as well.  Really no good reason.  Thanks very much!

Comment: The way you have the columns declared, there won't be nulls. Currently you have "not null" for each of them.

Comment: @Anssssss Correct, but my point was concat() will create the string sans conversion

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by specifying a format for the date conversion:

```
create table dbo.Example (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) not null,
    Email nvarchar(255) not null,
    DOB date not null,  -- I figure date is good enough
    RowHash as convert(nvarchar(66), hashbytes('SHA1', concat(
        convert(nvarchar(max), [Name]), 
        convert(nvarchar(max), Email),
        convert(nvarchar(max), DOB, 121)
    ))) persisted
    constraint [PK_Example] primary key clustered (Id asc)
);
```

The problem is that the default date-to-string conversion depends on system parameters, so it is not deterministic.  For a persisted column, all components need to be deterministic.

I would love to say that the documentation covers this exotic point in well-balanced detail.  Not quite.  You can get the idea from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017).  Just be forgiving -- it also applies to `date`, `datetime2` and other data types.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final result which is a combo of both answers above.  Thx very much for the help.

```
create table dbo.Example (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(100) not null,
    Email nvarchar(255) not null,
    DOB datetime2(7) null,
    RowHash as convert(nvarchar(66), hashbytes('SHA1', concat(
        convert(nvarchar(max), [Name]),
        convert(nvarchar(max), Email),
        convert(nvarchar(max), DOB, 121)
    ))) persisted
    constraint [PK_Example] primary key clustered (Id asc)
);
drop table dbo.Example;
```